# How to find the values that $x$ can take to be a real number?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, real-numbers

> $$3 \cdot \sqrt{x+4} + 5 \cdot \sqrt [8]{6-x}$$
>   - How to find the values that $x$ can take to be a real number?

I'm a bit confused. However, I want to show my thinkings:

$$ x + 4 > 0 \implies  x > -4$$

and

$$6-x>0 \implies  6 >x$$

My Kindest Regards,

Comment: great so you have $-4\leq x\leq6$. Problem solved.

Comment: @yanko Was it correct?

Comment: Just a weak inequality.

Comment: @Enzo That's almost correct, don't forget 0!

Comment: @gimusi Assume that it was $\sqrt [5] {x+2}$ what should we do? That's odd now.

Comment: @Enzo There could be a problem in the logical sense, because technically you didn't explain why it is not real for other $x$'s (I mean it could be hypothetically that both the terms are not real and then the sum is real).

Comment: @yanko yeah I forgot to write that.

Comment: You need the following reasoning as well : If $x<-4$ then the first summand is not real while the second is and so the sum is not real, if $x>6$ the first summand is real while the second is not real, so the sum is not real.

Comment: @for $\sqrt [5] {x+2}$ all values are fine to obtain real values

Comment: @Enzo Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct! You just haven't considered the case that the radicals could be $0$.

We have $$\sqrt{x+4}=0\implies x=-4$$ and $$\sqrt[8]{6-x}=0\implies 6=x$$

Hence your inequalities become $$x\ge-4,\,x\le6$$ or more succinctly $$-4\le x\le6$$

Answer (score 1):

You should set

$$ x + 4 \ge 0 \implies  x \ge -4$$

and

$$6-x\ge0 \implies  6 \le x$$

thus

$$-4\le x\le6$$